# Bootstrap 3 popover not working when inserted into webpage using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using AJAX to insert a [Bootstrap 3 popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) into my webpage.

My popover:

```
<a class="popup" rel="popover" data-content="<a href='/<?php echo $link; ?>/' title='<?php echo $title; ?>'><?php echo $text; ?></a>" data-placement="right">
    Click here
</a>
```

My JavaScript (which is located just before `</body>` in my webpage):

```
<script>  
    $('.popup').popover({
        html: true
    })
</stript>
```

My AJAX script works perfectly to insert the popover HTML into the webpage BUT the popover doesn't work when I click on "Click here". If I then reload the webpage, the popover works!

How can I get the popover to work straight after it is inserted into the page. I don't want to have to refresh the page.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: Sorry but I have it all on localhost

Comment: :( try to make a JS Fiddle otherwise, for me is impossible to know the read bug. Sorry :(

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a bug with the code because a page refresh makes the popover work. My JavaScript doesn't seem to recognise the popover is in the webpage until the page is reloaded manually.

Comment: The `.popover()` should be done once the AJAX call completes.. where is your ajax code?

Comment: @Skelly Thank you for the nudge. I've now added the script to my success function. May I ask why it doesn't work when I have my JavaScript in my webpage?

Comment: Because the element with class '.popup' doesn't exist yet.

Comment: As an alternative to changing my success function, could I use the .on() jQuery method? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: @Skelly Just to add - The reason I'm interested in an alternative to modifying the AJAX success function is I am using a WordPress plugin - if the plugin author decides to update the plugin and I upgrade - my changes will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

you should use toggle, otherwise it works once.

just add `data-toggle="popover"`

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top">
  Popover on top
</button
```